# How to distribute $n$ red balls between two bins to maximize the chance of sampling only red balls?

Tags: calculus, probability, average, balls-in-bins

Consider two bins that contain an unknown number of black balls.

We wish to split $n$ red balls (i.e., choose a number $x\in\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$ to place in a random bin) so that if we pick one ball at random from each bin we maximize our chances of sampling only red balls.

It seems that *regardless* of the number of black balls in each, we should split the red balls evenly.

Mathematically, show that for any positive numbers $b_1,b_2$ (representing the black balls) and $n$:

$$
\frac{x}{x+b_1}\cdot\frac{(n-x)}{(n-x)+b_2} + \frac{x}{x+b_2}\cdot\frac{(n-x)}{(n-x)+b_1} \le \frac{2\cdot (n/2)^2}{(n/2+b_1)\cdot (n/2+b_2)}.
$$

One way to do that is to consider the function $f(x)$
$$
f(x) = \frac{x}{x+b_1}\cdot\frac{(n-x)}{(n-x)+b_2} + \frac{x}{x+b_2}\cdot\frac{(n-x)}{(n-x)+b_1},
$$
derive it, and find its maximum.

I'm wondering if there's some averaging argument that we can use to simplify this proof.

---

Clarification:
Our goal is to choose the split $(x,n-x)$. We *cannot* determine whether $x$ will be in the bin with $b_1$ balls or the one with $b_2$ balls since we do not know $b_1$ and $b_2$. Therefore, I assume that $x$ will be placed with $b_1$ with prob. 1/2 and with $b_2$ with prob. 1/2.

Comment: Is $n $ assumed to be even?

Comment: @user, sure, let's assume that.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94494/discussion-on-question-by-r-b-how-to-distribute-n-red-balls-between-two-bins-t).